# NSMutableSet Error - Unexpected Identifier

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableSet *validOperations = [@"sin", @"cos", @"sqrt", @"π", @"+/-",@"+", @"-", @"*",@"/",nil];
```

I am having an Unexpected Identifier error with this, what am I doing wrong?

Sorry, if this question seems lame, but it's actually my first time coding with Objective-C so I don't really know what the problem is here, so experienced programmers, please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
NSMutableSet *validOperations = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects: @"sin", @"cos", @"sqrt", @"π", @"+/-",@"+", @"-", @"*",@"/",nil];
```

In order to create an `NSSet` or `NSMutableSet`, you need to call a method. There's no built-in syntax to create a set from a list of objects.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it, I just assumed that I could create a set in a Java-style manner.

Comment: Nope, not for sets. There is syntax for `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, and `NSDictionary`, though. Here's [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html) and the detailed [Clang reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: You'll find that NSSet/NSMutableSet aren't used terribly often in iOS / Cocoa programming.  Typically, it is all about NSArray and NSDictionary.